# Matlab: find second argmax

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, how do you calculate the second argmax of a vector? For a vector `A`, the max and argmax can be calculated as follows:

```
A = rand(1,4);

% calculate max and argmax
[val_max1, idx_max1] = max(A)
```

What is the best way to determine the 2nd max and argmax? That is, the 2nd largest value in `A` and the index of the 2nd largest value in `A`.